# incorrect ts suggestions in function overloading

Tags: typescript

TypeScript compiler is not providing accurate suggestions for the config parameter when calling the `fooBar` function with the 'view_product' type. While it correctly detects errors when an incorrect key is provided, it fails to enforce the presence of only one key as defined in the `FooFn` interface. Can I get the correct suggestions in this case?

```js
interface Window {
  fooBar: FooFn
}

interface FooFn {
  (method: 'event', type: 'view_product', config: { view_product_key: any }): void
  (method: 'event', type: 'update_cart', config: { update_cart_key: any }): void
}

window.fooBar('event', 'view_product', {}) // TypeScript incorrectly allows passing an object with more than one key
window.fooBar('event', 'view_product', { update_cart_key: 1 }) // TypeScript correctly flags an error for an incorrect key
window.fooBar('event', 'view_product', { view_product_key: 1 }) // TypeScript correctly allows a valid object with the right key
```

[image]

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOqgCYHsDuyDeAUMsjFlgEJxQBcyAYufSIQL6GGiSyIqNbMCxZAAoAthDAALLBjoByCADcI4eQBpkYAJ4AHCAqXAIOAPq6osgK4IwG5AiwgYwAOZ18yIyfOWMNsFMAawhtOjgQbWRWAEo6JSxgDGFxSRk5ZEUVNU0dfQUrXQw4SFMEajtNR2c3D2RC4tLyqECQsOQIqNj4xOT2QhxMXAA6MkpqESzVSszvMwtrW3t8WOQAejXkABU9CABlBChgXTBkUEcoKAhbABsouBub3ABnZF04Z%20fQVw6QZCwAEYAK2up0G0mQYiwVy0Ugi-xAKDaAyGOFG5CoUEmymm9nkc18ixmngaJQgZQqwVCdAAjNEYutNjt9AcjicHNCrrcojAbnBXK94dBLFBSNDfmcQBcuadkYMQNg0WNMdjsjN8cZ5n4AssvJrCf5bFT2nTVhttrtWcdTtLQXcOo8Xh0vA8kv9gaDkOCpLCUEdXFJZaEgA)

Comment: This is currently a limitation of IntelliSense, reported at [ms/TS#51047](//https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51047). Until that's addressed, you'd need to refactor to use something like generics, possibly as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/Nn5Rdw). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the link to issue. Your code looks interesting, can you tell me more in your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've run into a limitation of IntelliSense autosuggest, as reported in [microsoft/TypeScript#51047](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51047). It looks like overloads that differ by the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of their parameters end up being incorrectly lumped together in the completion lists.  Until and unless that issue is resolved, you'll need to either accept this or refactor to avoid overloads.

One way to do this is with [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) instead of overloads.  You can write a "mapping" interface which represents your parameters as an object structure.

```
interface ConfigMap {
  event: {
    view_product: { view_product_key: any };
    update_cart: { update_cart_key: any };
  };
}
```

With that type, you want a `FooFn` to accept a key of `ConfigMap` as its first argument, then drill down into that property and have the next argument be a key of that, and then the final argument should be the property value at that nested key.  This can be expressed as a call signature that uses generics and [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html):

```
interface FooFn {
  <K1 extends keyof ConfigMap, K2 extends keyof ConfigMap[K1]>(
    method: K1, type: K2, config: ConfigMap[K1][K2]
  ): void    
}
```

So a `FooFn` has two generic type parameters.  There's `K1` for the `method` argument, which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the [keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) of `ConfigMap`.  And there's `K2` for the `type` argument, which is constrained to the keys of `ConfigMap[K1]` (which is the property type at the `K1` key of `ConfigMap`).

And then `config` is of type `ConfigMap[K1][K2]`, the type of the property if you drill down into the `K1` property of `ConfigMap` and then the `K2` property of `ConfigMap[K1]`.

This behaves more or the same way in terms of accepted and rejected calls:

```
window.fooBar('event', 'view_product', { update_cart_key: 1 }) // error
window.fooBar('event', 'view_product', { view_product_key: 1 }) // okay
```

but now the IntelliSense is narrowed so that you only see the appropriate completions:

```
window.fooBar('event', 'view_product', {});
              suggestion:               ^ view_product_key
```

That's because when you write `window.fooBar('event', 'view_product',`  the compiler is able to infer `"event"` as `K1` and `"view_product"` as `K2`, and thus the type of `config` is `{view_product_key: any}`.  There is no trace of `update_cart_key` left in the call signature to get in the way.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not gonna be of any help as to why is doesn't work as expected, but may I suggest using [Distributive Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)?

The implementation can look like this:

```
interface Window {
    fooBar: FooFn
}

type ViewProductParams = {
    type: 'view_product',
    view_product_key: any
}

type UpdateCardParams = {
    type: 'update_cart',
    update_cart_key: any
}

interface FooFn {
    (method: 'event', params: ViewProductParams): void
    (method: 'event', params: UpdateCardParams): void
}

window.fooBar('event', { type: 'view_product' }) // error, view_product_key config option is not present
window.fooBar('event', { type: 'view_product', update_cart_key: 1 }) // error, update_cart_key is unexpected for this type
window.fooBar('event', { type: 'view_product', view_product_key: 123 }) // correct type and the view_product_key option is present
```

You can even remove the overload, since all the param types could be passed as a union (this also gives nicer and more precise errors):

```
interface FooFn {
    (method: 'event', params: ViewProductParams | UpdateCardParams): void
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I also thought about this option. But I have too many different options for this function and too many parameters. In this case my code will become too boilerplate

Comment: There are no distributive conditional types in this answer. Perhaps you mean "discriminated union"?

Comment: @jcalz yeah, my bad - that's the one